# How to disable button until an async function call is over?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a button on the frontend that calls an async method which then calls an external REST Controller to refresh (delete current -> create new) a Calendar. The problem is that if the button is clicked multiple times before the first REST call process is completed, it creates multiple calendars. I want to disable the refresh button until the async method (and the REST call inside of it) is finished. 
How can this be achieved? I am using Angular4.

I tried using a flag that I set as soon as the function is called and reset it at the end of the function. This did not work.

HTML button code:

```
<!-- refresh button -->
<button md-button type="button" class="mat-button active (click)="refreshCalendar(team)">
  Refresh
</button>
```

Async refreshCalendar method:

```
  async refreshCalendar(teamName: string) {
    // Some code ..

    this.calendarSvc.refreshCalendarForTeam(teamId);
  }
```

Async refreshCalendarForTeam method:

```
  async refreshCalendarForTeam(teamId: number) {
    // URL creation ..

    return this.http.post(url, {}) // REST call here
      .map(response => {
        return response.toString();
      }).subscribe(() => { });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Use a variable `IsCalling:boolean=false`. Your code would look like this:

```
IsCalling:boolean=false

callAsyncFunction()
{
    IsCalling=true;

    async refreshCalendar(teamName: string) {
        // Some code ..
        IsCalling=false;
        this.calendarSvc.refreshCalendarForTeam(teamId);
    }
}
```

Your HTML would be

```
<button [disabled]='IsCalling' md-button type="button" class="mat-button active (click)="refreshCalendar(team)">
  Refresh
</button>
```